# How can I get all id's from a database column into one single array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I fetch all the values from columns (like an id column) and put them into an array?

I'm using PDO API and I tried with other code, but it's not working for me.

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT Tid  from Playlist ');
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$result = $STH->fetch();

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ids_array[] = $result['Tid'];
}
```

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_*` with `PDO` ?!

Comment: yes i just tried with this way :p   i don't have more idea about mysql i just tried to use this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing `mysql_*` and `PDO`, which is obviously not going to work.

Just [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) your results and then just merge all rows into one array by simply looping through all rows with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and returning the id,  e.g.

```
$stmt = $DBH->query("SELECT Tid  from Playlist");
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$ids = array_map(function($v){
    return $v->Tid;
}, $result);

print_r($ids);
```

Comment: thanks , but there is a syntax error in your code . it's not working and i have no idea about array map to solve it by my self

Comment: @user44444 Just reload the page again. Just missed a curly bracket.

Comment: Thanks, great snippet!

Answer (score 8):

You can directly return an id array by specifying the `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`.

```
$stmt = $DBH->query("SELECT Tid from Playlist");
$ids_array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```